# triggering an event at the storyboard end

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, blend, expression-blend-4

I am new to silverlight and I want to trigger an even when the storyboard finsihes or ends. How would I go on doing that. I already have one trigger in storyboard at mouse enter. I am not sure if I can add more events there.
thanks

Comment: I think its stroyboard.complete

Comment: but I am not sure how to use it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "StoryBoardComplete" Behavior.  You'll find it in the Assets panel under "Behaviors".

EDIT: Sorry, I answered in a hurry and incorrectly from memory. I should have given more details when you said you were new to Silverlight and I should have verified my answer.

**CORRECTED ANSWER**:
Use a "StoryboardCompletedTrigger" on a Behavior.  Let's say you want to change the Fill property of a Rectangle when your Storyboard completes.  Add a Rectangle to your application:

[image]

Go to the Assets panel (same tab group as the Projects panel).  Open the category titled "Behaviors" and locate the "ChangePropertyAction".

[image]

Drag and drop one onto the Rectangle. Objects and Timeline will now look like so:

[image]

Note that the ChangePropertyAction item is selected.  Now go to the Properties panel:

[image]

In the Trigger section, click on the "New" button that I've highlighted for you.  This will open a dialog and let you pick a different TriggerType.  In this case you want a "StoryboardCompletedTrigger":

[image]

Fill in the Storyboard and PropertyName values.

[image]

Now when Storyboard1 completes the Rectangle's Fill property should change to Red.  Here is the compelte XAML code for this simple example:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
Width="640" Height="480">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.9" To="-360" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF0000F7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,133,0,225" Stroke="Black" Width="210" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:StoryboardCompletedTrigger Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Fill">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
            </ei:StoryboardCompletedTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="86,0,0,98" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="110">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

YMMV: This approach is for use with Behaviors.  Without knowing your situation I can't make a better recommendation, but this is the typical way to accomplish what you want.